# Install Ad Hoc distributed app on iOS via USB, using iTunes running on Windows

Tags: iphone, windows, ios7, itunes, ad-hoc-distribution

I would like to install an iOS7 iPhone app through an Windows iTunes. Following the [App Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html) I prepared the .ipa file. But the guide describes the installation on an iTunes running on a Mac only but not for Windows.
What do I need to do to get the app installed on a test device connected to an Windows iTunes?

Thanks

Comment: Try asking this on superuser.com.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know superuser.com. I saw similar question asked on stack overflow.com as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the windows explorer in the folder where your .ipa is. Open side by side iTunes. After that, drag & drop the .ipa file from the explorer window to the itunes sidebar where you have the music/apps/etc

Doing this, you are adding the ipa to the iTunes Library. After that, you just need to go to the itunes section of your devide, and select you App (the ipa) to install.

Comment: That sounds very easy. I read that iTunes on Windows can't deal with the .ipa file directly. Please give me some time to check that out before I can accept. Thanks so far.

Comment: Hello Paulo, it really worked. Thanks. I'm still suprized that there is no discription from Apple or other sources.

Comment: I belive Apple don't do that, because the only worry about their ecosystem. So, using a PC to evaluate a iOS App isn't their normal scenario. The normal scenario would be, someone using the Mac with XCode to deploy the app directly to the device.
Also, you have the hability to do a Over the Air deploy of Apps for testing, that's not well documented by Apple.

Comment: Where can I find more information about the over-the-air distribution?

Comment: You can follow this Guide
http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2011/01/21/1/how-to-distribute-your-ios-apps-over-the-air