# iPhone - Put App on Phone Using Windows Computer

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode-organizer

I have a problem: I am using a windows computer to code using Google Remote Desktop. I am writing an iPhone app for my phone. I dont want to release the app, I just want to get it on my iPhone. I do not have access to any kind of mac. Basically, I have an xcode project on a mac that I am accessing using Google Remote Desktop. How can I put this app on my iPhone. This is for a school project. It is time sensitive. Is there anything I could do with iCloud or iTunes or something? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You cannot put an app on your iPhone without a developer membership, which costs 99 dollars.  I'd suggest a web app if you need this for a school project.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to find a Mac to at least compile the code. After that, you can put it on your iPhone directly in Xcode - if, and only if, you've paid your $99 to Apple to get a development certificate.

You might be best off finding someone with a Mac and a membership in the iOS Developer Program to compile your app and run it on your phone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't sync an app to your phone without using Xcode. Xcode provisions the app using your developer certificate so that it can be installed on a device. This is part of Apple's software security and helps prevent malicious apps. As far as I'm aware Xcode is  the only app that will do the code signing and install.

To be a bit more precise, Xcode uses command line tools under the hood to perform the code signing and syncing, and these tools that are only available on OS X.

Answer (score 0):

You can install an app package (.ipa) using iTunes on Windows - refer to this answer - [install ad-hoc distribution over iTunes running on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20529678/install-ad-hoc-distribution-over-itunes-running-on-windows)

**BUT** as others have said, you need to have an iTunes developer program membership in order to generate the signed IPA file on your remote Mac.